# Load CoreData objects' string property into UIPickerView

Tags: uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, properties, uipickerview

Currently I have an entity named "Events" in a CoreData app.  "Events" has one string property named "eventName".

In the -(void)viewDidLoad I am trying to Fetch all the "Events" objects and load their "eventName" by alphabetical order into a UIPickerView.

The ultimate end goal is through the use of a textField, buttons and the pickerView being add new objects in and remove unwanted objects out.  Basically turning the UIPickerView into a UITableView.  Currently I am able to save objects to the CoreData store, but am not able to pull them/their properties out into the UIPickerView.

I am willing and able to share the project source code to anyone who wants it, or is willing to look at it to help out.

thanks
Chris

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I was able to find some of my answers below, I also posted the code.  But my current question is, is it possible/how to delete one of the CoreData objects from it being selected in the UIPickerView?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)update
{   
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CDPickerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"callName" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {     
        Event *theEvent = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *StringOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theEvent.callName];

        [array2 addObject:StringOne];

    }

    self.pickerData = array2;   
    [singlePicker reloadAllComponents];

}

-(IBAction)addCall{
    CDPickerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];   
    NSManagedObject *theEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [theEvent setValue:callField.text forKey:@"callName"];

    [context save:&error];

    callField.text=@"";

[callField resignFirstResponder];   
self.update;
}
```